# How update Setter password(Pwd) using scanner class and Constructor also there?

Tags: java, constructor, setter

I need to get a new password instead of old password
I have two java classes, while one contains the getters and setters the other is a driver class. I need the user input from the scanner in the driver class to be in one of the setters in the first class. The user input has to be a int because it will be used as a formula in the setter.

```
class Account
{
    private int Pwd;
    Account(int Pwd)                                         
    {
        this.Pwd=Pwd;
    }
    public void setPwd(int oldPwd, int newPwd)
    {
        if(this.Pwd==oldPwd)
        {
            this.Pwd=newPwd;
            System.out.println("Password is changed");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("password mismatch");
        }
    }
    public boolean verifyPwd(int pwd)
    {
        if(this.pwd==pwd)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;
class SbiDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in); //scanner
        Account a=new Account(int Pwd); 
        int oldPwd=s.nextInt();
        int newPwd=s.nextInt();
        setPwd(oldPwd,newPwd);  
    }                                
}
```

Constructor does not work well. I think I need to get a new password.

Comment: The constructor of `Account` expects an initial password. `new Account(int Pwd)` is illegal syntax and wouldn't make sense because `int Pwd` is a variable name, not a concrete value like `5`

Comment: How to initially get Password from user

Comment: You could print like "hey what's your initial password?", then get a password from the user like you do `int initial = s.nextInt()` and then create the account. That's usually how account creation works :) btw, variable names usually start lowercase `int pwd`, only class names start UpperCase

Comment: Example U try me any program ?

Comment: You should be able to translate this to `int initalPwd=s.nextInt();` and `Account a=new Account(initalPwd);`. The `Scanner` needs to exist beforehand obviously